# Calculation on part of a large array vs copying chunk and calculation

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

I have just been trying to optimize some code so things are a little faster and just wanted an explanation on what I have found.

The code is simply calculating the values at specific windows. So we have this snippet where it is calculated by looking at the values in the original array

When the user selects the window the calculation is done in, the start time and end time are set. The calculation then looks at the original data array between those times and does the calculation. Quick note, the arrays inside of the data dictionary are very large.

```
Dim Calc As Dictionary(Of String, Double) = New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
Dim data As Dictionary(Of String, Double()) = New Dictionary(Of String, Double())

 Dim total As Double = 0
 For r = starttime To endtime
    total = total + Math.Pow(data(key)(r), 2)
 Next
 Calc.Add(key, Math.Sqrt(total / length))
```

and then there is this method which turned out to be almost 100ms faster when doing the calculations for about 50 at a time. Over here it copys the chunk of those specific times to another array and then does the calculation

```
Dim temp(length) As Double
Array.Copy(data(key), starttime, temp, 0, starttime-endtime)
Calc.Add(val, Func(temp))

 Private Function Func(arr As Double()) As Double
    Dim total As Double = 0
    For Each value In arr 
        total = total + Math.Pow(value, 2)
    Next
    Return Math.Sqrt(total / arr.Length)
End Function
```

I would think that the added time from copying the array would cause it to fall behind? I am still trying to make this more efficient, so any further suggestions would be much appreciated :)

EDIT: Doing a bit of research found out, replacing

```
Math.Pow(val,2)
```

with

```
val*val
```

Knocked of another 100ms. :)

Comment: What do you mean resize them? I don't believe I am resizing any array?

Comment: Sorry, i've misread the code. I think we need a little bit more cotext to help to improve it. However, improving working code normally belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks WIll give that a try. I am just curious why method number one takes longer than 2.

Added a bit more explanation

Comment: Instead of Math.Pow have you tried just doing a multiplication? total + (value * value). The difference I see between the two as that in the first you do "data(key)" on every line. Have you tried removing this from the loop?

Comment: @the_lotus Thanks! I beat you to it by a minute! Found the difference to be about 100-120ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling). Based on the two example, one does not have data(key)

```
Dim total As Double = 0
Dim subData As Double() = data(key)

For r = starttime To endtime
   total = total + Math.Pow(subData(r), 2)
Next
Calc.Add(key, Math.Sqrt(total / length))
```

Since you are doing a simple pow2, I would suggest you do the math right in your function.

```
Dim total As Double = 0
Dim value As Double
Dim subData As Double() = data(key)

For r = starttime To endtime
   value = subData(r)
   total += value * value
Next
Calc.Add(key, Math.Sqrt(total / length))
```

Also, if you do this a lot, you could already save the pow2 values in a second array for future use.

```
Dim total As Double = 0
Dim subData As Double() = dataThatIsAlreadyPow2(key)

For r = starttime To endtime
   total += subData(r)
Next
Calc.Add(key, Math.Sqrt(total / length))
```

Comment: Updated original post with what data(key) is. It was a dictionary with a large array of doubles.

Took a look at loop unrolling and it definitely helped, thanks! 
Unfortunately I dont think saving the values will work for me, as where in the array the calculation is done changes often.